Python- 3D graph- axis range- how to change?
OSX 12.7.6 Python 3.13
I have looked at other related questions, but I don't see any that answer my question. I have a 3D scatter graph which works well. Launches quickly with Launcher, with no errors. (the file select window does not close until the app is terminated, but tIhave not found a solution and I can live with this)
All datapoints are normalized 0-1 (RGB values) . In order to get better resolution I need to adjust range (in this case) 0.2  - 0.6 as all values/coordinates fall within this, and having a range to 1.0 is just empty space. The Green (y) axis is what I want, but the red (x) blue (z) axis remain 0.2 - 1.0, I have tried an assortment of combinations  for the range of each...
Below is my code, and a screenshot of a plot. I need to be able to adjust as needed, as data sets will move around. What am I missing?
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False})

import  tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Toplevel
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(file_path)


df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
print(df.head)
print(df.columns)
root.iconify()


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim(left=0.2)
(0.2, 0.6)

ax.set_ylim(0.6, 0.2)

ax.set_zlim(bottom=0.2)
(0.2, 0.5)

for i in range(len(df)):
    ax.scatter3D(df['R'][i], df['G'][i], df['B'][i], 
                 marker=df['M'][i], c=df['C'][i], alpha=1.0)

ax.set_xlabel('Red')
ax.set_ylabel('Green')
ax.set_zlabel('Blue')

plt.show()

screen shot of plot

I removed the (left=0.2) and the (bottom=0.2)  Problem solved!

I removed the
left=0.2
and the
bottom=0.2.
This resulted in axis range as specified.
